# Nginx not redirecting port

Tags: nginx, tomcat, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, nginx-location

## Hello, I am running my tomcat application over port 8088 and have tried configuring nginx in front of  it as a reverse proxy. This is my conf:

```
   ` server {
    listen       8089;
    server_name  localhost;

    #charset koi8-r;

    #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_pass_header Content-Type;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8088/App/Home;
    }`     
So when access localhost:8089 , my tomcat application opens but all the resources files show 404 as they      are being fetched from http://localhost:8089/App/resources/*.*.

How can I make sure they are being fetched from 8088. What am I missing here?
```